# Change preferred NIC in default routes

Tags: centos, networking, route

I have a VM with CentOS 7.1 and two NICs:

- eth0, dhcp, 192.168.1.0/24, access to the host and the Internet.
- eth1, static, 10.0.0.0/24, between VMs only.

I have configured IP and connectivity is working as long as I ping machines on the same networks. But I have issues with my routes as traffic to any other network, for example `8.8.8.8`, is sent onto `eth1` instead of `eth1`:

```
$ ping -c 1 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.11 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

My current routes looks like this:

```
$ ip r
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1  proto static  metric 100
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  proto static  metric 101
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.11  metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.97  metric 100
```

How do I change the routes so that traffic destined for the Internet is routed onto `eth0` instead of `eth1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer:

I needed to change `DEFROUTE=yes` to `DEFROUTE=no` for the internal NIC and then restart the network:

```
sudo systemctl restart network
```